# How do i loop string array in c# more than once?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, loops, array-population

I can't quite figure it out how to loop through string array after the first initial loop has been done.

My code right now is:

```
    string[] assignments = new string[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};

    Array.Resize<string>(ref assignments, 99);
    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(assignments[i]);
    }
```

However, it seems that Resizing the array doesn't accomplish much, since arrays values after the 6th value is non-existant. 
I need it to keep looping more then once:
A
B
C
D
E
F A
B
C
D
E
F ... and so on, until the limit of 99 is reached.

Comment: Do you want your array to contain those repeated items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [mod operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/modulus-operator).

```
string[] assignments = new string[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(assignments[i % assignments.Length]);
}
```

[.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gW8uI4)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - fair enough. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [modulus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/modulus-operator) operator which "computes the remainder after dividing its first operand by its second."

```
void Main()
{
    string[] assignments = new string[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
    {
        var j = i % 6;
        Console.WriteLine(assignments[j]);
    }
}

0 % 6 = 0
1 % 6 = 1
...
6 % 6 = 0
7 % 6 = 1   
... etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

The obligatory LINQ solution, this extension comes in handy:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> RepeatIndefinitely<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    while (true)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Now your task is very easy and readable:

```
var allAssignments = assignments.RepeatIndefinitely().Take(99);
```

You can use a `foreach`-loop with `Console.WriteLine` or build a string:

```
string result1 = string.Concat(allAssignments);
string result2 = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, allAssignments)
```

Comment: I very much like this. However could it be considered a tad dangerous that the call to repeat indefinitely on its own will crash when it's evaluated?

Comment: @Dave: of course it's a bit dangerous, if you f.e. append `ToList` without a filter (f.e `Where` or `Take`) you will get an `OutOfMemoryException`. But since the name is pretty clear you should know what will happen if you try to take an 
infinite number of items ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about using mod

```
string[] assignments = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };

        for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(assignments[i%6]);
        }
```